# Java Method that prints 2D array diagonally in negative direction

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was able to write a method that prints a 2D array:

```
   {a,b,c},              
   {d,e,f},
   {g,h,i},
```

as so:

```
a db gec hf i
```

Here is the method:

```
 public static void d2(int[][] b){
   for( int k = b.length - 1 ; k > 0; k-- ) {
      for( int j = 0 ; j < b.length ; j++ ) {
        int i = k - j;
        if( i < b.length && j < b.length ) {
            System.out.print(b[i][j] + " " );}
          }
        System.out.println();}
      }
    }
```

Now I want to write a method that prints in diagonally in the negative direction, which would be:

```
 g dh aei bf c
```

What do I have to change in my original method to make it print out the other diagonal way?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: I tried this but the int k loop ended so it stopped printing in between the array. Would I have to add a second nested for loop?

     `public static void d2(int[][] b){
       for( int k = b.length - 1 ; k > 0; k-- ) {
           for( int j = 0 ; j < b.length ; j++ ) {
                int i = k + j;
                   if( i < b.length && j < b.length) {
                      System.out.print(b[i][j] + " " );}
                }System.out.println();}
            }
    }   
   `

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't getting the output you mentioned, instead got a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Here's a modified version of same program which gives the expected output:

```
    int b[][] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    // for (int i = (b.length * 2) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (b.length * 2); i++) {
        for (int j = i, k = 0; j >= 0; j--, k++)
            if (j < b.length && k < b.length)
                System.out.print(b[j][k] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

To reverse, simply un/comment the other `i` loop. The `i` loop acts as a counter or a level tracker (as in which diagonal are we traversing right now). So, based on the `i` value, `j` & `k` initialize themselves & loop through in the diagonal direction.

Since the direction is the same & you only want a reverse order, it's sufficient to change the `i` loop alone. So, instead of going from the `0th` to `nth` diagonal, it's reversed; `nth` to `0th` diagonal.